# How would you write the Multivariate Normal Distribution from scratch in Torch?

Tags: python, pytorch, distribution, torch

I would like to implement the Multivariate Normal Distribution in the Torch library from scratch. My implementation is not giving me the same output as the distribution at `torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal`. What part do I have wrong?

I tried implementing an equation of the Multivariate Normal Distribution I found on the internet but it doesn't match the output of the Torch MultivariateNormal distribution. I don't see an equation for it in the [Torch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#multivariatenormal).

My code

```
import torch

µ = torch.tensor([[-10.5, 2.0], [-0.5, 2.0]])
cov = torch.tensor([[12.0, 8.0], [12.0, 40.0]])
pos_def_cov = torch.matmul(cov, cov.T)
Σ = torch.linalg.cholesky(pos_def_cov)

x = torch.randn([1])
d = torch.tensor(x.shape[0])

(1 / torch.sqrt(2 * torch.pi**d) * torch.abs(Σ)) * torch.exp(-0.5 * (x - µ).T * Σ**-1 * (x - µ))
```

Typically the value in the upper right corner of the matrix is zero.

```
tensor([[ 0.2842,  0.0000],
        [12.4068,  8.7792]])
```

The Torch distribution with the same matrices.

```
torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(µ, pos_def_cov).sample()
```

The output doesn't have a constant zero value like my output does.

```
tensor([[-5.4596,  7.1297],
        [ 0.8562, -7.6340]])
```

This is the equation I believe I have implemented correctly from scratch in Torch above. I think my problem may have something to do with my Cholesky Decomposition and making the covariant a positive definite matrix, if this is a fine equation to use and I implemented it correctly.
[image]

I have looked at the source code of [`torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/distributions/multivariate_normal.html#MultivariateNormal) and I find it too abstract to get a foothold in.

Answer (score 1):

Σ should be a symmetric matrix by definition. In your provided example, the following code is not correct.

```
Σ = torch.linalg.cholesky(pos_def_cov)
```

Moreover, the pdf should return a scalar but not a matrix. The following code is also wrong. You should not use `torch.abs()` but `torch.det()`

```
(1 / torch.sqrt(2 * torch.pi**d) * torch.abs(Σ)) * torch.exp(-0.5 * (x - µ).T * Σ**-1 * (x - µ))
```

The problem is you are trying to compare a probability density function with a randomly generated sample.

A correct demo is the following code:

```
import torch

µ = torch.tensor([-10.5,2.0])
cov = torch.tensor([[12.0, 8.0], [8.0, 40.0]])

x = torch.randn(2)
d = torch.tensor(x.shape[0])

# your manual implementation of pdf
torch.log(1 / torch.sqrt((2 * torch.pi)**d * torch.det(cov)) * torch.exp(-0.5 * torch.sum((x - µ) * torch.mv(torch.inverse(cov), (x - µ)))))

# pdf from pytorch 
torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(µ, cov).log_prob(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I need to learn more about this... You said "Σ should be a symmetric matrix by definition." From what I read the matrix needs to be 'positive definite' and that was done by multiplying it by itself transposed? Should I have done something else? I thought I was taking a sample in my version and the torch version. I ultimately do want to use it to take samples.

Comment: Σ = torch.mm(L, L.T) whereas L is something from Cholesky decomposition. But you are passing L to pdf. It's more a statistical problem rather than a code problem.

Comment: I'm getting `RuntimeError: vector + matrix @ vector expected, got 1, 2, 2`

Comment: Open a new notebook/file e.g. colab, and copy & paste the code. RuntimeError should not occur.

Comment: I see. My fault. Though this is returning a single tensor. i.e. `tensor(-10.1154)`. `torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(µ, cov).sample()` returns `tensor([-12.3057,   8.1244])`

Comment: ```.log_prob()``` is consistent with what you has been working with but ```.sample()``` is a single realization. You should not compare a random sample. If pdf are the same, they must define the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to recreate `.sample()` from  `torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal`

Comment: I'm looking into the source code of `torch.distributions.MultivariateNormal` again, and it seems to be just multiplying the mean with the covariance. It's almost as a simple as that. The only addendum to that are some accommodations to different sized tensors and it does set a sample range based on something to do with the tensors that I haven't gotten a grasp on yet. All day I was thinking there was a long formula behind this.

Comment: Just wanted to share that we can also input the lower triangular Cholesky matrix as an attribute to `torch.distributions.multivariatenormal.MultivariateNormal`  which is called `scale_tril`. 
Along with other attribute mean we can create the distribution. 

From the source description, 
scale_tril (Tensor): lower-triangular factor of covariance, with positive-valued diagonal.
also,  Using:attr:`scale_tril` will be more efficient.